# C++ Execution policy not working with std::map

Tags: c++, execution

I have successfully used std::execution::par_unseq policy on ubuntu 20.04 with gcc 9. However I encounter a strange behavior where it didn't work with maps but worked with vectors

Example 1:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared<Foo>>> ProblemsType;
ProblemsType values;
FillValues(values);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, values.begin(), values.end(), [](ProblemsType::value_type value) {
    // Do something
}
```

Example 2:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared<Foo>>> ProblemsType;
ProblemsType values;
FillValues(values);
std::vector<std::pair<std::string>, std::vector<std::shared<Foo>>> valuesAsVector;
FillVectorWithMapValues(valuesAsVector, values);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, valuesAsVector.begin(), valuesAsVector.end(), [](std::pair<std::string>, std::vector<std::shared<Foo>> value) {
    // Do something
}
```

#1 doesn't work but #2 does. I checked by watching cpu usage with htop and saw all core used (and several thread spwaned) with #2. With #1 only one core was used.

I checked and std::map::iterator is a *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* that satisfies *LegacyForwardIterator*.

Is there anything special with std::map preventing the use of execution policy par_unseq ?

Comment: Please provide [MRE]

Comment: A `std::map` is implemented as an RB tree, and "separating" that into groups that can be ran on there own threads would be a hard thing to do.  `std::vector` on the other hand is trivially "separated" into buckets that separate threads can work on.

Comment: I'd imagine whichever standard library you are using requires a random access iterator to work in parallel

Comment: I think it's implementation defined. In VS2022 it runs a few threads more than I've got hyperthreads (27, and I've got 24 physical HT's).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything special with std::map preventing the use of execution policy par_unseq ?

You weren't *prevented* from using `par_unseq`, presumably the implementation chose not to do anything different from the non-policy overload.

It's then a quality-of-implementation issue as to whether the implementation does anything different with the extra freedom the policy gives it.